# How to deal with unlimited columns situation on Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, count, multiple-columns, having

```
    SELECT ITEM_TITLE 
    FROM (SELECT ITEM.ITEM_TITLE
    FROM ITEM JOIN ITEMSELLER ON ITEMSELLER.IS_ITEMID = ITEM.ITEM_ID
    JOIN SELLER ON SELLER.SELLER_ID = ITEMSELLER.IS_SELLERID
    GROUP BY ITEM.ITEM_TITLE
    HAVING COUNT(ITEMSELLER.IS_ITEMID)>1);
```

For Oracle,

I would like to list only the items that have been sold by multiple sellers with the seller's name (everyone).

The code works fine but I can't list the seller name, and want it to compatible when the number of sellers increase (means the columns can be unlimited depends on how many sellers have sold the same item).

From the code above there are 3 tables,

```
ITEM : has item_title, item_id

SELLER : has seller_id, seller_fname, seller_lname
```

ITEMSELLER : has is_itemid (FK with item_id), is_sellerid (FK with seller_id)

The results should be like this

```
items        seller_1      seller_2    seller_3.........seller_x

-------      --------      -------     -------          --------

item_a       John          William     (null)           (null)

item_b       William       Bruce       Julia            (null)

item_c       Julia         John        William          Marry
```

or

```
items        sellers

-------      --------  

item_a       John, William

item_b       William, Bruce, Julia

item_c       Julia, John, William, Marry
```

Comment: for multiple records(means multiple seller) you will get in different - different rows, then I don't think that you will have to worry about multiple columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this in Oracle you can use `LISTAGG ()` as below -

```
SELECT Item_Title Items, Listagg(Seller.Seller_Fname, ',') Within
 GROUP(
 ORDER BY Seller_Fname)
  FROM Item
  JOIN Itemseller ON Itemseller.Is_Itemid = Item.Item_Id
  JOIN Seller ON Seller.Seller_Id = Itemseller.Is_Sellerid
 GROUP BY Item.Item_Title
HAVING COUNT(Itemseller.Is_Itemid) > 1;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works !
I haven't know this syntax before.